# Getting invalid_grant error when using django oauth provider

Tags: django

I am using django oauth provider and curl like in the example on the documentation to get an access token but I keep getting an error message.  {error: invalid_grant}. How do I fix it? I would like to get this running for Android.

Comment: What did you search and try? You have just posted = "I get this error and what should I do".. No good. Let us know something more. Like the things that you searched and tried to fix. [FYI](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-doubleclick-for-advertisers-api/FZo-6ZZGeyQ)

Comment: The errors are from other Apis and not from oauth provider. I tried looking at the docs for information about the error but I can't get anything.